# what happens when state change in a DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, rendering

I have read few articles regarding the Real DOM and Virtual. But still, I am having confusion about understanding the concept of Real DOM and Virtual DOM.

1. When we update any element in a webpage, does it render the whole web page or just that specific part of the page? For example - If I have a paragraph and a button and I want to change the color of a paragraph with a button click then what will happen, will the browser render the whole page or just that part of the page in REAL DOM.
2. If it just re-render the specific part only then why do we need to use the virtual dom in react?

Answer (score 1):

If you write careful code modifying the color of the paragraph on the real dom, then the browser will only have to do a minimal amount of work. The entire page shouldn't need to reflow in most cases. But as your website gets more complicated, the modifications you're making to the dom get more complicated as well, and it becomes easier to make mistakes which can force the browser to do expensive updates.

The purpose of the virtual dom is to let you write code without worrying about how to update the real dom in an optimal way. React does comparisons for you using the virtual dom (ie, objects in memory describing the page), and then figures out the minimum set of changes to make to the real dom.

So the virtual dom isn't going to be faster than carefully crafted manual updates. But it makes it very easy to write pretty fast code.